# Symfony3 Form component trying to pass null to a type hinted method in PHP 7

Tags: php, symfony-forms, symfony, php-7

In my entity class I have defined all the expected argument types for the setters and return types of the getters.
Later, when I have a form which uses the said class, I get an error if some of the fields in the form is empty because the form component tries to pass null to the setter instead of string.

I get the following exception when I submit the form:

> #### Expected argument of type "string", "NULL" given
>
> <sup>500 Internal Server Error - InvalidArgumentException</sup>

The exception is thrown from `vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/PropertyAccess/PropertyAccessor.php at line 254`

Is there a way to convert the "null" value to empty string before passing it to the object, and let the validator argue about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see two options here:

**Quick and Dirty - make the argument passed to the setter optional:**

```
public function setTitle(String $title = null)
{
    $this->title = $title;
    return $this;
}
```

**Probably better - use a [data transformer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html) in the FormType:**

Data transformers allow you to modify the data before it gets used.

```
   $builder
    // ...
        ->add('title', 'text')
    // ...
    ;

    $builder->get('title')->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
        function($originalInput){
            return $string;
        },
        function($submittedValue){ 
            // When null is cast to a string, it will be empty.
            return (string) $submittedValue;
        }
    ));
```

I've posted [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32229354/3000068) before using this to retrieve method to retrieve an Entity object before. See that if it helps to see a more complicated example.

Comment: When using the second way, the data is transformed and the exception is not thrown, but the validation doesn't work anymore. I tried looking at the documentation but couldn't find why.

The first option works, but as you said, it's kinda dirty.

Comment: P.S. The validation doesn't work only on those fields that an data transformer is added. For example, if I have an "name" and "email" fields, and I add a data transformer to the "name" field, then if I leave it empty and put some invalid email address in the "email" field, there will be an validation error message only for the "email" field.

Comment: @Angelov, Loud and clear. Unfortunately, its been a while since I've worked with data transformers and the validation component and I don't remember all the nuances with them; I'm not sure how I could help more than I have. It might be helpful for the question to see some of these validation rules though - if I recall correctly, there are multiple ways to use the validator.

Comment: I added an issue on the PHPDDD project on github which offers a workaround at least for working with Commands using CQRS: https://github.com/webdevilopers/php-ddd/issues/18

Answer (score 11):

If an Entity Property cannot be `null` (*and you use PHP 7.1+*), then also the application of the [nullable return type declaration](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php) sounds more like a dirty and fast workaround to maintain a direct data binding between Entities and Forms (*using the Symfony Form Component*).

A better global approach (*in my opinion*) is to decouple the Form data binding from your Entities using a DTO (*Data Transfer Object*), that is a simple POPO (*Plain Old PHP Object*) to contain your form data.

Using a DTO will allow you to maintain a strict type hinting in your Entities (*no loss of data consistency*) and will decouple Form data binding (*but also data validation*) from your Entities.

DTO's allows reusability and have many other advantages.

Some useful references about the use of DTO's with Symfony Forms:

- [Avoiding Entities in Forms (*by Iltar van der Berg*)](https://stovepipe.systems/post/avoiding-entities-in-forms)
- [Rethinking Form Development (*by Iltar van der Berg*)](https://stovepipe.systems/post/rethinking-form-development)
- [Symfony Forms 101 (*by Bernhard Schussek the creator of the Form component*)](https://speakerdeck.com/webmozart/symfony-forms-101)
- [Don't Use Entities in Symfony Forms. Use Custom Data Objects Instead](https://blog.martinhujer.cz/symfony-forms-with-request-objects/)
- [Entities should always be valid](https://ocramius.github.io/doctrine-best-practices/#/50)